# Slim not recogninsing classes from generated-classes file when combined with propel

Tags: get, http-post, propel, slim

When I run Propel through Slim, the Propel's generated classes are not getting loaded, and i am unable to post or get data from Database.

I have integrated Propel with Slim. All my db code is in Propel files.
In Foo.php

```
<?php 
namespace App;
//propels required files
class Foo extends someclass{
  public function foodata()
  {
    echo "hellow propel-Slim";
    $info = new Info();       // this class is in generated_classes
    $info->setInfodetails('medical info'); 
  }
}
?>
```

In index.php

```
<?php
  //Slim's required files
  $app->post("/details/information", "\App\Foo:foodata"); 
?>
```

So whenever I run `/details/information` url it should call the function `foodata` and insert the data in table info using class `Info`.
Instead it will just print the echo statement and give me error.

```
hellow propel-Slim
Fatal error: Class 'App\Info' not found in foo.php.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please specify what doesn't work and what is your displayed error? A bit of code would be useful too.

Comment: you haven't including the file anywhere that I see. Are you using Slim via Composer or the old autoloader?